# Fetch data when one of filters changes (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I have a situation and I need your advice. I am going to create a panel of filters, that can be inputs or selects. When one of these filters changes I have to fetch with filters values to a server. I have a parent component with useStates for every filter

```
const [filterOneValue, setFilterOneValue] = useState()
const [filterTwoValue, setFilterTwoValue] = useState()
...
```

and then I put value/setValue to filters (imagine that I have maybe 5 of them)

```
<FilteOne value={filterOneValue} onChange={setFilterOneValue}/>
<FilteTwo value={filterTwoValue} onChange={setFilterTwoValue}/>
...
```

I am thinking about how should I describe logic and that send to server updated data when one of those filters would be changed

I have an idea is using useEffect with all states dependencies for example:

```
useEffect(() => {

  fetch(url, {
    data: {
     filter1: filterOneValue,
     filter2: filterTwoValue
     ...
    }
  })

}, [filterOneValue, filterTwoValue, ...])
```

What do you think? Maybe it is a better way to do that

Comment: Yeah your solution should work just fine, ```useEffect``` with the proper depdency array is perfect for situations like this.

Comment: useEffect is the right decision but you can explore useMemo which will protect apps from random rendering if there is no data changes

Comment: Abu, could you please make an example of how should I use useMemo in my situation?